# list_entry of linked_list of linux kernel returns random value

Tags: c, linux, memory-management, linked-list, linux-kernel

I have an array of linked list called:minor_arr.
the type of the node is msg.
I'm trying to add a new node to the linked list.
the problem starts, when I try to read the value of any entry. I get random value.
Anyone sees why?

```
typedef struct {
    struct list_head list;
    char msg_value[msg_len];
    short len;
     int channel_id;

} msg;

static struct list_head  **minor_arr;
```

And inside the code:

```
    char *priv_buffer;
    new_msg = kcalloc(sizeof(msg), 1, GFP_KERNEL);
    INIT_LIST_HEAD(&new_msg->list);
    new_msg->channel_id=channel_id;//something is wrong here, can't set right channel_id

    priv_buffer = new_msg->msg_value;
    debug("device write before for");
    printk("%zu",length);
    for (i = 0; i < length; i++)
        get_user(priv_buffer[i], &buffer[i]);
    list_add(minor_arr[minor], &new_msg->list);
    printk("A:channel id in new_msg list should be %d and it's %d",channel_id,list_entry(minor_arr[minor], msg, list)->channel_id);
    return i;
```

something clearly goes wrong as it is printed:

```
[   21.704368] A:channel id in new_msg list should be 11 and it's -730005930
```

Comment: where is minor_arr allocated?

Comment: The first parameter to `list_add` is **element** and the second is **list**. It seems that you wrongly specify parameters to that function (according to your words, `minor_arr[minor]` is a list, and you want to add message into it). Also, `list_entry(minor_arr[minor], msg, list)` has no sence: you attempt to interpret list (`minor_arr[minor]`) as element.

Comment: SInce `minor_arr` is a `struct list_head **`, it points to an array of `struct list_head *` and each element needs to be pointing to an initialized `struct list_head`. Can you show that code? Then `list_add(minor_arr[minor], &new_msg->list);` should be `list_add(&new_msg->list, minor_arr[minor[);` and then `list_entry(minor_arr[minor], msg, list)` should be `list_first_entry(minor_arr[minor], msg, list)` since the new entry was addded to the front of the list.